# How to do ssl termination on apache tomcat

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, tomcat

I want to do SSL termination on apache tomcat.

I understand how to configure SSL on tomcat, but a bit confused about the word SSL termination.

Situation is this: We have an apache server that load-balances traffic to two tomcat servers.

Where exactly should the SSL certificate be applied so that I can access the application with a URL like:

```
https://myapp.example.com ( loadbalancer url )
```

still terminating on Tomcat?

The tomcat hosts are myapp1.example.com and myapp1.example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL (really TLS) termination just means that the outer TLS wrapper in HTTPS ends at the URL that faces the user. So when the user goes to https://myapp.example.com, Apache decrypts the TLS layer to get the HTTP request, and the TLS ends there.

From there, Apache can proxy the connection to your back end servers. That can be with or without TLS, but if it needs to use TLS, Apache can start a new TLS connection to them. All you need is

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myapp.example.com
  SSLEngine on

  <Location />
    ProxyPass        ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

or whatever your proxy configuration to Tomcat is.

Comment: This means if user is accessing an SSL enabled URL ( loadbalancer URL ) , then SSL is essensially termintated at load balancer. Let me know if my understanding is correct.  Additionally, the backend application server can also be TLS enabled right ?

Comment: That's correct.